# Git plugin won't display metrics on new code when comparing different branches

Tags: git, sonarqube

I am analysing my code with SonarQube, using [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Git+Plugin) Git plugin.

When doing a pull request, I am analysing the coverage on the Git `master` branch and then the coverage on some feature branch `feature/some-feature`, on the same SonarQube project.

If the coverage is smaller on the feature branch, I am failing my build.

However, SonarQube won't display the `Coverage on New Code` metric(probably because I am analysing different branches).

How can I make SonarQube show `Coverage on New Code` when I am building different Git branches of the same project?

Answer (score 0):

When you perform pull request analysis, *most* rules are run. However, there are a few rules, such as those for coverage and duplications, that only run server-side after the analysis report has been submitted.

Because pull request analysis is by definition a "preview", it does not submit an analysis report to the server, and thus cannot raise coverage issues.